# script that lists all files in a directory and subdirectories sorted by size, listing only file names not complete paths

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm looking for a script that lists all files in a directory and subdirectories sorted by size, listing only file names not complete paths.

`find . -type f -exec ls -lhS {} \+` works but gives the path.

`find . -type f -printf '%f\n'` also works but I'm not sure how to sort it or if it's possible to include the file sizes here as well.

Comment: You can pipe output to grep `find . -type f -exec ls -S {} \+ | grep -o "[^/]*$"`

Comment: Actually I'm not sure right now - do you want to remove only leading path from the result (the same string for all files) or entire path for all files (including subdirectories) so that you will have only `basename` of the files? Also what is desired format of the output - your two commands gives completely different results.

Answer (score 2):

If your `find` supports it, you can use `%s` in `-printf` ("File's size in bytes").

If your `sort` supports nul-delimited input (`-z`), you can then do:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %f\0" | sort -nz | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

If your system supports `zsh` command, then in `bash` script you can run

```
zsh -c 'ls -lhS -- **/*(.D)'
```

This probably requires some explanation:

- `zsh`: other than `bash`, more powerful shell with a lot of features
- `-c`: take next argument as a command to execute by `zsh`
- `ls -lhS`: according to your question this is the command you want to execute
- `--`: takes care of strange filenames which may start with `-` character
- `**`: *glob* matching over multiple directories
- `*`: standard *glob* - matching all files in those directories
- `()`: *glob qualifiers* specifying which files and in which order should be selected
- `.`: we select only plain files (equivalent of `type f` in `find`)
- `D`: include dot-files (hidden files) in the result

---

After re-reading the question I suppose you rather want to delete the entire path from the result, not only leading part. This still can be done with `zsh`:

```
print -l **/*(.OLDe:'reply=${REPLY##*/}':)
```

but that may be little too much as this is not question about `zsh` tricks after all, so I will propose "standard" solution with `find` + `sed`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'ls -lhS "$@" | sed "s| \..*/| |"' {} \+
```